# An example of Vargas set

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics

Let us consider the following definitions:

A finite or countable subset $x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots \subset [0,1]$ is said to be **lacunary** if there exists a constant $0 < \lambda < 1$ such that $x_{k+1} < \lambda x_{k}$ for all $k$.

A finite set $U \subset [0,1]$ with $\#V = N$ is a **Vargas set** with constant $Q$ if
\begin{eqnarray*}
\max \! \left\{\#U' : U' is \,\,a\,\, lacunary \,\,subset \,\,of \,\, U\right\}  \,\,  =  \,\,  Q\log N.
\end{eqnarray*}

Show that the sequence $1/N, 2/N, \ldots 1$ (or $2^{-N}, 2^{1-N}, \ldots 1$) is a Vargas set with $Q = 1$.

Comment: The set $\{2^{-N}, 2^{1-N}, \ldots 1\}$ is lacunary for any $1/2<\lambda<1$ with the enumeration $x_k=2^{-k}$ for each $k$. Also the number $Q\log N$ is often not-integer, so in these cases it cannot be a size of a set.